# How to specify the correct library to use when LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes path to both 32 bit and 64 bit versions

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have a written a small c++ project on a linux box. I am able to compile and link the code properly with the -I and _L,-l commands.

I read on the net that while running the code, we need to have the path to the .so files in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. Now the box that I am using is 64 bit and there is another application that uses 32 bit version of the library. So the LD_LIBRARY_PATH has paths to both versions of the library.

When I try to run my application eg. ./xyz arg1 arg2, I get the following error

```
./DaemonCpp: error while loading shared libraries: libldap.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I think this is because it is trying to load 32 bit version instead of 64 bit version. I tried changing the order in which the paths are mentioned in LD_LIBRARY_PATH such that the path to 64 bit comes first but still I get this error. Is there a way I could direct the app to use the 64 bit version of the library.

As a secondary question to my primary problem, when we are linking the c++ code, we do specify the library path using the -L and library name using -l. Then it should have known which library to use when I run the executable and I shouldn't have got this error in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your second question, you only used `-L` to specify the link time path. You need to also add `-rpath=<path>` for each path that you specify with `-L`. to get it to look at run-time as well.

If you're using the gcc/g++ driver for linking, then you should use `-Wl,-rpath=<path>`

e.g. library libfoo.so in `/opt/libs/lib64`:

```
gcc -o test test.o -L/opt/libs/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/opt/libs/lib64 -lfoo
```

In answer to your first question, if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is causing issues, then your first port of call is `ldd` which shows the paths to the libraries that are being linked at run-time. Start with an empty string and work up from there.

Thirdly, if the reason that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set is because there are libraries in /opt/lib, etc... then you should be adding these paths to your `/etc/ld.so.conf` and using `ldconfig` to update the search map for these libraries. This will typically save you from needing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable at all.